# Rails: Heroku и фотографии

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Здравствуйте.

Я только начал использовать Heroku для развёртывания и обнаружил одну проблему.

Я сделал маленький сайтик, по типу блога - в нем есть посты с фотографиями, все работает нормально, но вот задеплоил на Хероку - на следующий день часть фотографий пропала.

И тут возник вопросик: куда они пропали, почему, и как это можно предотвратить.

Comment: попробуйте повторить все это на своей локальной машине в production

    rails s -e production

Помню у меня когда-то была схожая проблема, пути к файлам были разные в разных окружениях.

Comment: В том-то и дело, когда я захожу - загружаю посты и работаю с ними, все отлично... если я зайду через 40 мину будет все норм, а вот если через 2 дня то часть пропадает - самое главное что только часть фотографий, не все

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Давненько не работал с хероку, но раньше там была FS доступная только для чтения. Возможно сейчас они позволяют заливать фото, но складируют их в директорию tmp, которая периодически очищается.

В качестве решения можно воспользоваться [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) из [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/).

Comment: Всё правильно сказал. На хероку каждый инстанс работает отдельно и занимается только одним -- обработкой запросов. Для хранения данных нужно использовать другие сервера. Можно Amazon s3. Также можно поискать что-нибудь среди аддонов на heroku.

Comment: Увы, аддонов таких нету. Я в своё время делал аддон файлового хранилища с прозрачной обёрткой над `File`, `Dir` и пр., но из закрытой беты он не вышел, потому что даже на неё не было желающих.

Answer (score 3):

Есть плагин, использующий дропбокс в качестве хранилища [paperclipdropbox](https://github.com/dripster82/paperclipdropbox)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku очищает директорию и не дает возможность хранить у себя фотографии. Лучше использовать [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)